# Why central mikrotik router not routing secondary networks (PPTP VPN)?

Tags: routing, router, vpn

I have 3 offices:

```
1.2.1.0/24 main1      office
1.2.2.0/24 secondary2 office
1.2.3.0/24 secondary3 office
```

There are three `Mikrotik 951Ui-2HnD` (current-firmware: `3.18`) in each office:

```
main1:      LAN: 1.2.1.1 | WAN: XXX.XXX.XXX.115
secondary2: LAN: 1.2.2.1 | WAN: XXX.XXX.XXX.112
secondary3: LAN: 1.2.3.1 | WAN: XXX.XXX.XXX.116
```

There are no any `/ip firewall` rules yet in each mikrotiks.

#### Main1 mikrotik configuration

```
/interface pptp-server server
set enabled=yes

/ip address
add address=1.2.1.1/24 interface=bridge-local network=1.2.1.0
add address=XXX.XXX.XXX.115/29 interface=ether1-gateway network=XXX.XXX.XXX.112

/ip route
add distance=1 gateway=XXX.XXX.XXX.113
add distance=2 dst-address=1.2.2.0/24 gateway=172.16.1.2
add distance=2 dst-address=1.2.3.0/24 gateway=172.16.1.3

/ppp secret
add local-address=172.16.1.1 name=secondary3 password=123 profile=pptp-in remote-address=172.16.1.3 service=pptp
add local-address=172.16.1.1 name=secondary2 password=123 profile=pptp-in remote-address=172.16.1.2 service=pptp
```

#### Secondary2 mikrotik configuration

```
/interface pptp-client
add add-default-route=no allow=mschap1,mschap2 connect-to=XXX.XXX.XXX.115 dial-on-demand=no disabled=no keepalive-timeout=60 max-mru=1450 \
    max-mtu=1450 mrru=disabled name=pptp-out1 password=123 profile=default-encryption user=secondary2

/ip address
add address=1.2.2.1/24 interface=bridge-local network=1.2.2.0
add address=XXX.XXX.XXX.117/29 interface=ether1-gateway network=XXX.XXX.XXX.112

/ip route
add distance=1 gateway=XXX.XXX.XXX.113
add distance=1 dst-address=1.2.1.0/24 gateway=172.16.1.1
add distance=1 dst-address=1.2.3.0/24 gateway=172.16.1.1
```

#### Secondary3 mikrotik configuration

```
interface pptp-client
add add-default-route=no allow=mschap1,mschap2 connect-to=XXX.XXX.XXX.115 dial-on-demand=no disabled=no keepalive-timeout=60 max-mru=1450 \
    max-mtu=1450 mrru=disabled name=pptp-out1 password=123 profile=default-encryption user=secondary3

/ip address
add address=1.2.3.1/24 interface=bridge-local network=1.2.3.0
add address=XXX.XXX.XXX.116/29 interface=ether1-gateway network=XXX.XXX.XXX.112

/ip route
add distance=1 gateway=XXX.XXX.XXX.113
add distance=1 dst-address=1.2.1.0/24 gateway=172.16.1.1
add distance=1 dst-address=1.2.2.0/24 gateway=172.16.1.1
```

### Secondary2 see's Main1, but not see's secondary3

```
[secondary2 ] /ping 1.2.1.1 ... ok
[secondary2 ] /ping 1.2.3.1 ... timeout

[secondary2 ] /tool traceroute 1.2.3.1
  # ADDRESS                          LOSS SENT    LAST
  1 172.16.1.1                         0%    1     2ms
  2                                  100%    1 timeout
  ...

[secondary2 ] /ip address print  
  Flags: X - disabled, I - invalid, D - dynamic 
  #   ADDRESS            NETWORK         INTERFACE                                                                                          
  0   1.2.2.1/24         1.2.2.0         bridge-local                                                                                       
  1   XXX.XXX.XXX.117/29   XXX.XXX.XXX.112   ether1-gateway                                                                                     
  2 D 172.16.1.2/32      172.16.1.1      pptp-out1  


[secondary2 ] /ip route print
  Flags: X - disabled, A - active, D - dynamic, C - connect, S - static, r - rip, b - bgp, o - ospf, m - mme, 
  B - blackhole, U - unreachable, P - prohibit 
   #      DST-ADDRESS        PREF-SRC        GATEWAY            DISTANCE
   0 A S  0.0.0.0/0                          XXX.XXX.XXX.113             1
   1 A S  1.2.1.0/24                         172.16.1.1                1
   2 ADC  1.2.2.0/24         1.2.2.1         bridge-local              0
   3 A S  1.2.3.0/24                         172.16.1.1                1
   4 ADC  XXX.XXX.XXX.112/29   XXX.XXX.XXX.117   ether1-gateway            0
   5 ADC  172.16.1.1/32      172.16.1.2      pptp-out1                 0
```

### Secondary3 see's Main1, but not see's secondary2

```
[secondary3 ] /ping 1.2.1.1 ... ok
[secondary3 ] /ping 1.2.2.1 ... timeout

[secondary3 ] /tool traceroute 1.2.2.1
  # ADDRESS                          LOSS SENT    LAST
  1 172.16.1.1                         0%    1     2ms
  2                                  100%    1 timeout
  ...

[secondary3 ] /ip address print  
 Flags: X - disabled, I - invalid, D - dynamic 
 #   ADDRESS            NETWORK         INTERFACE                                                                                          
 0   1.2.3.1/24         1.2.3.0         bridge-local                                                                                       
 1   XXX.XXX.XXX.116/29   XXX.XXX.XXX.112   ether1-gateway                                                                                     
 2 D 172.16.1.3/32      172.16.1.1      pptp-out1


[secondary3 ] /ip route print
 Flags: X - disabled, A - active, D - dynamic, C - connect, S - static, r - rip, b - bgp, o - ospf, m - mme, 
 B - blackhole, U - unreachable, P - prohibit 
  #      DST-ADDRESS        PREF-SRC        GATEWAY            DISTANCE
  0 A S  0.0.0.0/0                          XXX.XXX.XXX.113             1
  1 A S  1.2.1.0/24                         172.16.1.1                1
  2 A S  1.2.2.0/24                         172.16.1.1                1
  3 ADC  1.2.3.0/24         1.2.3.1         bridge-local              0
  4 ADC  XXX.XXX.XXX.112/29   XXX.XXX.XXX.116   ether1-gateway            0
  5 ADC  172.16.1.1/32      172.16.1.3      pptp-out1                 0
```

### Main1 see's both

```
[main1 ] /ping 1.2.2.1 ... ok (mikrotik secondary2)
[main1 ] /ping 1.2.2.2 ... ok (bd_server secondary2)
[main1 ] /ping 1.2.3.1 ... ok (mikrotik secondary3)
[main1 ] /ping 1.2.3.2 ... ok (bd_server secondary3)

[main1 ] /tool traceroute 1.2.3.2
  # ADDRESS                          LOSS SENT    LAST     AVG    BEST   WORST STD-DEV STATUS                                               
  1 172.16.1.3                         0%    3   0.6ms     0.7     0.6     0.8     0.1                                                      
  2 1.2.3.2                            0%    3   0.6ms     0.8     0.6     1.3     0.3

[main1 ] /ip address print
  Flags: X - disabled, I - invalid, D - dynamic 
  #   ADDRESS            NETWORK         INTERFACE                                                                                          
  0   1.2.1.1/24         1.2.1.0         bridge-local                                                                                       
  1   XXX.XXX.XXX.115/29   XXX.XXX.XXX.112   ether1-gateway                                                                                     
  2 D 172.16.1.1/32      172.16.1.3      <pptp-secondary3>                                                                                      
  3 D 172.16.1.1/32      172.16.1.2      <pptp-secondary2>   

[main1 ] /ip firewall filter<SAFE> /ip route print
  Flags: X - disabled, A - active, D - dynamic, C - connect, S - static, r - rip, b - bgp, o - ospf, m - mme, 
  B - blackhole, U - unreachable, P - prohibit 
  #      DST-ADDRESS        PREF-SRC        GATEWAY            DISTANCE
  0 A S  0.0.0.0/0                          XXX.XXX.XXX.113             1
  1 ADC  1.2.1.0/24         1.2.1.1         bridge-local                  0
  2 A S  1.2.2.0/24                         172.16.1.2                    2
  3 A S  1.2.3.0/24                         172.16.1.3                    2
  4 ADC  XXX.XXX.XXX.112/29   XXX.XXX.XXX.115   ether1-gateway                0
  5 ADC  172.16.1.2/32      172.16.1.1      <pptp-secondary2>             0
  6 ADC  172.16.1.3/32      172.16.1.1      <pptp-secondary3>             0
```

Comment: What is `gateway=172.16.1.1`?  Your default gateway?  Your 1.2.x.x NICs are on a different subnet, each needing their own default gateway for inter-LAN routing.

Comment: `172.16.1.1` - vpn ip of main1; 
`172.16.1.2` - vpn ip of secondary2; 
`172.16.1.3` - vpn ip of secondary3. See the `/ppp secret` configuration section of main1. As @mmv-ru correctly answered, I missed the route `add distance=1 dst-address=172.16.1.0/24 gateway=172.16.1.1`. The problem is solved. Thanks to @mmv-ru!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. 1.2.0.0/16 is bad address space for LAN, except it really public IP.** Use private addresses.

**2. ping from secondary2 get source IP 172.16.1.2, and secondary3 don't have route to reply (really it reply over default route, whats wrong).**

It can be fixed in many ways, but simplest for You - add appropriate routes.

Secondary2:

```
 /ip route
 add distance=1 gateway=XXX.XXX.XXX.113
 add distance=1 dst-address=1.2.1.0/24 gateway=172.16.1.1
 add distance=1 dst-address=1.2.3.0/24 gateway=172.16.1.1

 # missing route
 add distance=1 dst-address=172.16.1.0/24 gateway=172.16.1.1
```

Similar for secindary3

Or add preferred-source for routes

Secondary2:

```
 /ip route
 add distance=1 gateway=XXX.XXX.XXX.113
 add distance=1 dst-address=1.2.1.0/24 gateway=172.16.1.1 preferred-source=1.2.2.1
 add distance=1 dst-address=1.2.3.0/24 gateway=172.16.1.1 preferred-source=1.2.2.1
```

Similar for secindary3

**3. Or just ignore it. It "problem" for routers, not for hosts behind it.**

If You need ping for diagnostic, define src-address of LAN router interface:

```
/ping 1.2.3.1 src-address=1.2.2.1
```